# Vscode used ESP-IDF can`t use openocd

Tags: esp32, openocd, esp-idf

When i use ESP-IDF, use esp32-c3 board, i can`t frash, it show

`OpenOCD Exit with non-zero error code 1`

and output:

```
Licensed under GNU GPL v2
For bug reports, read
    http://openocd.org/doc/doxygen/bugs.html
debug_level: 2

force hard breakpoints
adapter speed: 5000 kHz

Info : Listening on port 6666 for tcl connections
Info : Listening on port 4444 for telnet connections
❌ Error: no device found
Error: unable to open ftdi device with vid 0403, pid 6010, description '*', serial '*' at bus location '*'
❌ Error: no device found
Error: unable to open ftdi device with vid 0403, pid 6014, description '*', serial '*' at bus location '*'

[Stopped] : OpenOCD Server
```

[how it was wrong][1]
[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/YushI.jpg

I try to rebuild and frash and it doesn`t word correctly.

How to fix it?